# Osherove TDD Kata 1: String Calculator

Tags: python, strings, python-3.x, unit-testing, regex

I implemented [Roy Osherove's TDD Kata 1: String Calculator](http://osherove.com/tdd-kata-1/) using Python 3.5.2 and the `unittest` module. The full description can be found at the link, it's a bit lengthy for this post.

The jest of it is to implement various string parsing and simple numbers logic to add numbers together which are passed as a delimited string, e.g.: `"1,2,3"` returns 6.

---

I followed true TDD principles to the best of my knowledge, in that for each requirement I first wrote a failing test, then made it pass, rinse & repeat, refactoring along the way.

Note that `test_incorrect_input_types` was not part of the requirement, but rather is a test that I do out of habit to make sure the correct type is passed to the function.

I'm interested in any and all ways I could improve this code. In particular, I'm looking for ways to make the TDD approach as clear and solid as possible.

---

## Unit tests:

```
import unittest

class TestAddStringNumbers(unittest.TestCase):
    """Tests for `add_string_numbers` function."""

    def test_incorrect_input_types(self) -> None:
        """Test that non-string inputs fail"""
        incorrect_inputs = [
            None,
            42,
            3.1415,
            [],
            {}
        ]
        for input_ in incorrect_inputs:
            self.assertRaises(TypeError, add, input_)

    def test_empty_string(self) -> None:
        """Test empty string as input"""
        input_ = ""
        expected = 0
        actual = add(input_)
        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)

    def test_1_number(self) -> None:
        """Test a single number as input"""
        input_ = "42"
        expected = 42
        actual = add(input_)
        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)

    def test_2_numbers(self) -> None:
        """Test 2 numbers as input"""
        input_ = "42,99"
        expected = 141
        actual = add(input_)
        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)

    def test_many_numbers(self) -> None:
        """Test many numbers as input"""
        input_ = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"
        expected = 55
        actual = add(input_)
        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)

    def test_negative_numbers(self) -> None:
        """Test that input with negative numbers fails"""
        input_ = "-1"
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, add, input_)
        input_ = "-1,2,-3"
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, add, input_)

    def test_numbers_greater_than_1000(self) -> None:
        """Test that numbers greater than 1000 are ignored"""
        input_ = "1,1001,2"
        expected = 3
        actual = add(input_)
        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)
        input_ = "1001,2001,3001"
        expected = 0
        actual = add(input_)
        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)

    def test_newline_delimiter(self) -> None:
        """Test input separated by newlines instead of commas"""
        input_ = "1\n2\n3"
        expected = 6
        actual = add(input_)
        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)
        input_ = """1
        2
        3"""
        expected = 6
        actual = add(input_)
        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)

    def test_invalid_delimiters(self) -> None:
        """Test that input with invalid delimiter placement fails"""
        input_ = "1,,2"
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, add, input_)
        input_ = "1,2,"
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, add, input_)
        input_ = ",1,2"
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, add, input_)

    def test_custom_delimiters(self) -> None:
        """Test that custom delimiters can be used with `//[delim1][delim2]\n` syntax"""
        input_ = "//[***]\n1***2***3"
        expected = 6
        actual = add(input_)
        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)
        input_ = "//[***][&&]\n1***2&&3"
        expected = 6
        actual = add(input_)
        self.assertEqual(expected, actual)
```

## Implementation:

```
from typing import List
import re

def add_string_numbers(numbers: str) -> int:
    """
    Add numbers passed in the form of a delimited string of numbers.
    For example, "1,2,3" returns 6.

    Delimiters are handled in the following ways:
    - The standard delimiter is a comma `,`
    - Newlines `\n` are always acceptable delimiters, e.g.:
        1\n2\n3
    - Additional delimiters can be declared with the following syntax
      added before the beginning of a delimited string:
        //[delim1][delim2]\n
      ...then used as delimiters. For example:
        //[***][&&]\n1***2&&3
      which will be parsed to:
        1,2,3
    """
    if not isinstance(numbers, str):
        raise TypeError("Input must be of string type")
    if numbers == "":
        return 0
    number_list = parse_into_list(numbers)
    result = 0
    negatives = []
    for num in number_list:
        try:
            num = int(num)
        except ValueError:
            raise ValueError("Input could not be converted to int")
        if num < 0:
            negatives.append(num)
        else:
            if num <= 1000:
                result += num
    if negatives:
        raise ValueError("Negatives not allowed: {0}".format(",".join(map(str, negatives))))
    return result

def parse_into_list(numbers: str) -> List:
    """Parse a string of numbers into a list"""
    numbers = handle_delimiters(numbers)
    return numbers.split(",")

def handle_delimiters(numbers: str) -> str:
    """
    Handle delimiters according to the `add` function requirements.
    """
    alt_delims = ["\n"]
    if numbers.startswith("//"):
        delims_header = get_delimiters_header(numbers)
        delims = get_delimiters(delims_header)
        for delim in delims:
            alt_delims.append(delim)
        numbers = cleanup_numbers_string(numbers, delims_header)
    for delim in alt_delims:
        numbers = numbers.replace(delim, ",")
    return numbers

def get_delimiters_header(numbers: str) -> str:
    """Helper to handle the `//...\n` header and return the section containing the delimiters"""
    re_delims_header = re.compile(r"""
        //    # match beginning delimiter
        (.*)  # capturing group of 0 or more of any char
        \n    # match ending delimiter
        """, re.VERBOSE)
    return "".join(re.findall(re_delims_header, numbers))

def get_delimiters(delims_header: str) -> List:
    """Helper to handle each individual delimiter and return a list containing them"""
    re_delims = re.compile(r"""
        \[      # match a literal [
        (       # start capturing group
        [^]]*   # match anything except a closing ] 
        )       # close capturing group
        \]      # match a literal ]
        """, re.VERBOSE)
    return re.findall(re_delims, delims_header)

def cleanup_numbers_string(original: str, delims_header: str) -> str:
    """Helper to remove the delimiters header section and return only the delimited list"""
    return original.replace("//{0}\n".format(delims_header), "")
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally I think your code is good. I personally would do things slightly differently. However I don't think there are really any major, or minor, problems. However I don't really know testing in Python, and so won't comment on that.

Some things I'd do differently are:

- I personally don't like erroring whilst handling another error. Even more so when both raise the same error, but with different messages. And so I'd just stick to using `int` without a `try-except`.
- Personally I'd prefer to use a comprehension than a for loop. And so I'd change lines 26 to 37 to three comprehensions.
- I prefer using `sum` over manually adding numbers. `sum(i for i in numbers if i <= 1000)` is easy to read and, IIRC, faster.
- If I came across `parse_into_list` in the wild, I'd think it should take a delimiter argument. However that's still in the numbers argument. Instead I'd go for a `split_calculator_input` function. This would return just numbers. And so I'd use something like the below, which I think is slightly easier to read than your functions.

  ```
  def split_calculator_input(input):
      delimiter, numbers = re.match(r'(?s)^(?://\[([^\n]+)\]\n)?(.*)$', input).groups()
      delimiter = '|'.join((delimiter or r',][\n').split(']['))
      return re.split(delimiter, numbers)
  ```

---

I had a go at doing this myself, since it's a one-time thing I didn't split the code into a lot of functions, but came up with the following:

```
def add_string_numbers(input):
    if not input:
        return 0
    delimiter, numbers = re.match(r'(?s)^(?://\[([^\n]+)\]\n)?(.*)$', input).groups()
    delimiter = '|'.join((delimiter or r',][\n').split(']['))
    numbers = [int(i) for i in re.split(delimiter, numbers)]
    negatives = [i for i in numbers if i < 0]
    if negatives:
        raise ValueError('Negatives not allowed {} found'.format(negatives))
    return sum(i for i in numbers if i <= 1000)
```